# Guardian API, JSON parsing jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have data in JSON format from the Guardian API's open platform I would like to parse this in jquery and I currently stuck trying to display results onto my HTML div.

The format of the data is as follows: [Guardian JSON results](http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=world%20news&format=json&api-key=ky5zy8mds5r25syu36t9kmzj)

My code that I am trying to work with is as follows

```
    function processFootballData(footballData){
    footyStuff = footballData;
    var thisContainer = document.getElementById( "results" );
    var listTmp = document.createElement( "ul" );
    var tmpList = "";
    for( var i=0; (i<footyStuff.results[0].length) && (i<100); i++ ) {
            if( tmpList.length <= 0 ) {
                tmpList = footyStuff.results[0][ i ];
            }
            else {
                tmpList = tmpList + "," + footyStuff.results[0][ i ];
        }
    }

    var footballURL = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=football&format=json&api-key=ky5zy8mds5r25syu36t9kmzj";
    $.getJSON( footballURL,
            function( thisData ) {
            var data = thisData;

            for( var key in data ) {
                    var thisSublist = document.createElement( "ul" );
                    thisSublist.setAttribute('style', "border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 80%;");
                    var thisItem = document.createElement( "li" );
                    var footyResults = data[key].results[0];

                    if( data.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                        var duyList = document.createElement("li");
                        duyList.setAttribute('style', "padding-bottom: 10px;margin-top:-15px;margin-left:53px;font-size:12px;");
                        duyFooty = document.createTextNode(footyResults);
                        duyList.appendChild(duyFooty);
                        thisItem.appendChild(duyList);
                    }

                    thisItem.appendChild( thisSublist );
                }
                listTmp.appendChild( thisItem );
        }
        thisContainer.appendChild( listTmp );
});

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `jsonp` request, because the Guardian API is blocking cross-domain requests.  Use the JQuery [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType: jsonp`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: footballURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function( thisData ) {
        var data = thisData;
        // etc ...
    }
});
```

Your DOM-generation Javascript is a bit of a mess ... but it's easy to get lost writing that kind of code.  I'd strongly recommend using some kind of micro-templating engine to handle the data-to-HTML conversion stuff.

---

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/UTBd6/5/) of how to do this using [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

```
// create HTML template with data tags
var template = "<ul>{{#results}}<li><ul><li><a href='{{webUrl}}'>{{webTitle}}</a></li></ul></li>{{/results}}";

// render output
var output = Mustache.render(template, thisData.response);

// add to the DOM
$("#results").html(output);
```

---

[Here's the same example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rc6a/1/) using [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  Same idea, but different implementation that lets you write the template as markup:

```
<script type='text/template' id='article-template'>
    <% _.each(results, function(article) { %>
    <ul>
        <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; width: 80%;">
            <a href='<%= article.webUrl %>'><%= article.webTitle %></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

​
And the script to render:

```
var template = _.template($("#article-template").html());
var output = template(thisData.response);
$("#results").html(output);
```